# Merge CSVs with PowerAutomate

Tags: power-automate

I am experimenting with the flow editor in PowerAutomate to merge a bunch of CSVs from OneDrive that I am syncing via rclone.

The structure is:
OneDrive(Root)/Folder/Subfolder/*.csv

I would like to merge them into a dataset (master CSV) that I can use with PowerBI.
Because this dataset is updated daily, new csvs will get added to the folder, thus my triggering event is "When a file is created"

The automation looks like this:
[image: PowerAutomate FLow]

- When a file is created >
- Initialize a String Variable >
- Find files in folder >

  - Search Query: *
  - Folder: Same as #1
  - FileSearch Mode: OneDriveSearch
- Apply to each >

  - Get File content
  - Append to string variable
- Compose (string variable) >
- Create file >

  - File Path: whatever/path/
  - File Name: whatever.csv
  - File Contents: Outputs

The automation runs fine, and creates my master csv.
Except it's blank!
What's going on?

When a File is Created:
[image: When a File is Created]

Initialize Variable:
[image: Initialize Variable]

Find Files in Folder:
[image: Find Files in Folder]

Apply to Each:
[image: Apply to Each]

Append String to Variable:
[image: Append String to Variable]

Compose:

[image: Compose]

Create a File:

[image: Create a File]

At the end of the day, I get a CSV with some data written to it. *Previously, I thought it was blank, but it does, indeed have data.. but it appears truncated.

[image: Output]

Something to note here... it looks like it retains the headers..
It looks like it grabbed the first 31 files, but there are 229 files in that folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the output at each append step and the last two where it composes and creates the file.